# Changing Image from TrueColor to 1Bpp Palette?

Tags: linux, image, process

Is there an easy way to take a TrueColor Image (24 Bit, Bitmap in this case) to a 1Bpp Image (Palette, Convert to Bitmap).

I know of imagemagick convert which can do conversion, but for some reason when I tried doning
convert -type Palette -depth 7 truecolor.bmp 1bpp.bmp

I know that you do it programatically, but isnt there an easier way?

Thanks

Comment: What easier way are you looking for? If you do a fixed threshold conversion you will get a terrible result. Some type of dynamic thresholding would be the best approach. The content of the images matter as well, but if they're color photographs of black and white documents, dynamic thresholding will be your best bet. I created my own algorithm that's pretty simple, but it's not something that I want to share.

Comment: oh sorry the above command convert -type Palette -depth 7 truecolor.bmp 1bpp.bmp didnt work. I rather not waste time coding something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Everyone for you help and interest (sarcasm to the max) but I found a solution.

```
convert -colors 2 -depth 1 truecolor.bmp 1bpp.bmp
```

will do the trick

Thanks